# extjs 3.4 modify label html content with it's renderer

Tags: extjs

I want to set the html for the label with it's renderer, how can this be achieved?
I already tried but failed to succeed. Can someone please give an example?

Comment: You should present some code.

Answer (score 0):

this.setText('Something') may work